# Explain this conditional sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If I were taller, I would not buy those heels.

Does this mean I still have the opportunity to get tall
and if I become tall in near future, I will not buy heels? Or have I already bought the heels and thinking about future?

I know its type 2 conditional but negative construction is confusing me.

Comment: FYI: No need for "please" here. People might be offended by abusive language, but not by lack of "please."

Comment: @KentaroTomono there's nothing gruff or brusque about how this question was asked. Its tone is perfectly OK. It's when some users write "I want to know", or worse, "I wanna know"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I were taller, I would not buy those heels.

Based on this sentence we cannot deduce:

(a) How tall the person is, or whether or not they may become taller in the future. The person may be tall or short, and they may still be growing or they may have already stopped growing. 'If I were taller' is purely a hypothetical statement, it does not imply that the person will or will not grow taller.

(b) Whether or not the person has already purchased the heels. However, it is likely that they have not yet bought them, because if they had done so then they are more likely to have said, 'If I were taller, I would not have bought those heels.'

From this sentence we can deduce that the speaker thinks that the heels would not be suitable for them if they were taller than their current height.